# MVC Razor two level Model for ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way in the view to drill down one level to get the data object in the GenericValues? I know that I can change the model around to make it work but I didnt want to add extra model classes?

View

```
<div class="form-group row">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedLanguage)
     @Html.ListBoxFor(
           x => x.selectedLanguage,
           new SelectList(Model.ListOfLanguages, "Value.Value", "Value.Name"),
           new { id = "multiselectLanguage", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Model

```
public List<LanguageModel> ListOfLanguages { get; set; }

    public class LanguageModel
    {
        public string ISOCode { get; set; }
        public GenericValues Values { get; set; }
    }

public class GenericValues
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to get `list<GenericValues>`:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
          x => x.selectedLanguage,
          new SelectList(Model.ListOfLanguages.Select(x => x.Values).Distinct(), "Value", "Name"),
          new { id = "multiselectLanguage", @class = "form-control" })
```